# impyla hangs when connecting to HiveServer2

Tags: python, hive

I'm writing some ETL flows in Python that, for part of the process, use Hive. Cloudera's impyla client, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla), works with both Impala and Hive.

In my experience, the client worked for Impala, but hung when I tried to connect to Hive:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect

conn = connect(host='host_running_hs2_service', port=10000, user='awoolford', password='Bzzzzz')
cursor = conn.cursor()          <- hangs here
cursor.execute('show tables')
results = cursor.fetchall()
print results
```

If I step-into the code, it hangs when it tries to open a session ([line #873 of hiveserver2.py](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/blob/master/impala/hiveserver2.py#L873)).

At first, I suspected that a firewall port might be blocking the connection, and so I tried to connect using Java. To my surprise, this worked:

```
public class Main {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://host_running_hs2_service:10000/default", "awoolford", "Bzzzzz");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Since Hive and Python are such commonly used technologies, I'm curious to know if anyone else has experienced this problem and, if so, what did you do to fix it?

Versions:

- Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.5.1
- Python 2.7.11 | Anaconda 2.3.0
- Redhat 6.7

Comment: I saw this "hangs forever" thing happens when a non-secure client tries to connect to a secure server. In this case, the server side handler thread may crash when it is processing the message from the client before it could send anything back. The client will thus keep waiting indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Dropbox's [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) package and it worked perfectly:

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="host_running_hs2_service", port=10000, username="awoolford")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
for table in cursor.fetchall():
    print table
```

I'm not sure why the Impyla client didn't work, but at least we can move forward.

Comment: but I get an error when I type "from pyhive import hive". The error is "ImportError: No module named builtins". Probably, python can't find hive.py in the Pyhive package. What should I do?

Comment: I have got solved this import issue. For those facing it:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291533/why-importerror-no-module-named-builtins-appears-after-importing-hive-from-py

Answer (score 1):

```
/path/to/bin/hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.authentication=NOSASL

from impala.dbapi import connect

conn = connect(host='host_running_hs2_service', port=10000, user='awoolford', password='Bzzzzz', auth_mechanism='NOSASL')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('show tables')
results = cursor.fetchall()
print results
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked for me: --hiveconf hive.server2.authentication=NOSASL . In my configuration, authentication was set to NONE.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following block to `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` did the trick for me:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>NOSASL</value>
</property>
```

Thanks to @ozw1z5rd's comment for pointing me in the right direction!