# Why "ImportError: No module named builtins" appears after importing hive from PyHive package?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have a simple question to ask. I have been trying to execute HIVE queries from Python using [impyla](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla) package. But I stuck into [cursor problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854145/impyla-hangs-when-connecting-to-hiveserver2), already a question has been asked on stackoverflow. In this question, a user answered and advised to use [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) instead.

Therefore, now I am trying to execute HIVE queries from Python using PyHive. But unluckily, I am stuck at another issue which seems to be not that complicated. As soon as I execute the following line in python I get an error:

```
In [18]: from pyhive import hive
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-747088b97eb4>", line 1, in <module>
    from pyhive import hive

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pyhive\hive.py", line 13, in <module>

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pyhive\common.py", line 8, in <module>

ImportError: No module named builtins
```

Can anyone indicate where I am getting it wrong? Since, I have already **successfully** installed the PyHive package on my machine, so I don't expect this to appear. I have been searching allot to find a reason of this error. It will be really a great time saver if I know the solution today. Thank you very much for your time and support.

**UPDATE**

I am using:

1. Windows 7 (64-bit)
2. Python 2.7 (32-bit)
3. Anaconda2 4.1.1 (32-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python 3 the module `__builtin__` was renamed to `builtins`.

It is possible that you have installed a python 3 package and are trying to run it with python 2.

Comment: YES, you are right. I removed Python27 and installed Python35 and it worked. Thanks :)